# How to create inline-records (IRRE) using DataHandler in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, datahandler

In our case we have a table A which contains IRRE records using table B. Inside a backend module we import an XML file to import those records for table B.

All records/data for table A is available.
All data for table B is available, except the new uids/identifiers.

Based on https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/6.2/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/ I have to set the identifier `NEWxxxx` for all new created records.

I'm importing a large number of records at once. Can I generate those identifiers in a loop and process all records at once or do I have to run the whole datamap-handling record by record ?

Besides the identifier, is there any field i have to set on the parent record which contains the IRRE record ?

No translations/workspaces/other relations are involved.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't have to create the data record by record, but for mass-execution, you have to ensure, these `NEW...` ids are unique and not re-used for different record-data.

Answer (score 8):

The DataHandler in TYPO3 is using the following array structure to create new or update existing records - this is valid up to and including TYPO3 CMS 8:

```
$dataMap = ['<table-name>' => [
    '<record-uid>' => ['<field-name>' => '<field-value>']
];
```

Existing records use the integer value of the record's `uid` field, e.g. `123`, new records use some random but unique identifier that are prefixed with `NEW`, e.g. `NEWa2b3c4f8` created by `uniqid('NEW', true)` - since TYPO3 CMS 7 `StringUtility::getUniqueId('NEW')` can and should be used for that.

### Generic Example

Let's assume the following records shall be created:

- a new content element in table `tt_content`
- two new inline file references for table `sys_file_reference` for field `tt_content.image`

  - referencing to existing `sys_file` record with uid `123`
  - referencing to existing `sys_file` record with uid `234`

---

```
// generating unique identifiers for records to be created
$ttContentId = 'NEW58d5079c8741c822627844'; // StringUtility::getUniqueId('NEW')
$fileRefId1st = 'NEW58d506f3cd0c4159344142'; // StringUtility::getUniqueId('NEW')
$fileRefId2nd = 'NEW58d50714c1226092562338'; // StringUtility::getUniqueId('NEW')
```

---

#### Preparing data-map

Hava a close look to `tt_content.image`, this is actually defining the (new) inline references, defined by a comma separated values of new records or existing records - this could either be `NEWabc,NEWdef`, `123,234,345` or `NEWabc,123,NEWdef`, mixing new and existing record references.

```
$dataMap = [
  'tt_content' => [
    'NEW58d5079c8741c822627844' => [
      'title' => 'My new content element',
      'bodytext' => 'Look at the following images...',
      'CType' => 'textpic',
      // $fileRefId1st & $fileRefId2nd, the sorting order is defined by this as well
      'image' => 'NEW58d506f3cd0c4159344142,NEW58d50714c1226092562338',
    ],
  ],
  'sys_file_reference' => [
    'NEW58d506f3cd0c4159344142' => [
      'uid_local' => 123,
      'title' => 'Image #123',
    ],
    'NEW58d50714c1226092562338' => [
      'uid_local' => 234,
      'title' => 'Image #234',
    ],
  ]
];
```

#### Preparing command-map

```
// the command-maps is similar to the data-map to copy, localize, move records
// however, it's not required in this scenario and thus stays empty
$commandMap = [];
```

#### Executing DataHandler

```
$dataHandler = new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler();
$dataHandler->start($dataMap, $commandMap);
$dataHandler->process_datamap();
// $dataHandler->process_cmdmap(); // if $commandMap should be processed as well
```

If you need the `uid` of the created records, this can be resolved from the internal DataHandler record mapping. For example, the following code resolves the new `uid` of the created `tt_content` record:

```
// fetching the actual record ID, e.g. results in 333
$ttContentId = $dataHandler->substNEWwithIDs['NEW58d5079c8741c822627844'];
```

### Notes

Defining the references happens in the example above directly for the field `tt_content.image`, which can contain `NEW...` ids as well as existing integer ids. The behaviour for the is the same for all reference types in TYPO3:

- TCA type `inline`, for all variants (plain, `foreign_field`, `MM`)
- TCA type `select`, for all variants (plain, `MM`)
- TCA type `group`, for all variants (plain, `MM`)

Passing data through `DataHandler` ensures that log entries are created, and the in most cases modifications can be reverted using TYPO3's history/rollback module.

Besides that, it's possible to execute mass actions - the invocation of `DataHandler` is not limited to just on aggregate (the `tt_content` record in the example above). However, the `NEW...` ids have to be unique and must not be re-used during mass-executions to avoid side-effects.

### Transformed to `table_a` & `table_b` scenario

Transforming this to the `table_a` and `table_b` scenario of the initial question, the `$dataMap` might look like the following. Of course you have to determine which references to `table_b` are bound to `table_a`.

```
$dataMap = [
  // existing records of table_a, thus using the real ids
  'table_a' => [
    '11' => [ 'reference_field' => 'NEWb1,NEWb2' ],
    '22' => [ 'reference_field' => 'NEWb3,NEWb4' ],
    '33' => [ 'reference_field' => 'NEWb5,NEWb6' ],
  ],
  // new records to be references for table_b, thus using NEW... ids
  'table_b' => [
    'NEWb1' => [ ... field values of this particular table_b record ... ],
    'NEWb2' => [ ... field values of this particular table_b record ... ],
    'NEWb3' => [ ... field values of this particular table_b record ... ],
    'NEWb4' => [ ... field values of this particular table_b record ... ],
    'NEWb5' => [ ... field values of this particular table_b record ... ],
    'NEWb6' => [ ... field values of this particular table_b record ... ],
  ],
];
```

### Notes on identifiers

Identifiers like `NEWb1` are kept simple intentionally - usually those identifiers are composed by prefix `NEW` and a (pseudo-)random hexadecimal string `abdc...`.

The TYPO3 core is using [`$id = StringUtility::getUniqueId('NEW')`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/StringUtility.php#L85-L96) to create those unique identifiers. However, that also can be achieved using `$id = 'NEW' . bin2hex(random_bytes(10);` - identifiers just have to be unique for this particular process.

Comment: Thank you for that thorough writeup!

Comment: In v9 I had to fill sys_file_reference with more data: 
`[
                    'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                    'uid_local' => $_file->getUid(),
                    'tablenames' => 'tx_slider_domain_model_layer',
                    'uid_foreign' => $_newL,
                    'fieldname' => 'media',
                    'pid' => 1,
]` - uid_local was not enough in my case.

Comment: It is not working if the identifier have an underscore. So e.g. `NEW_b_1` is not working but `NEWb1` is fine.

Comment: `NEW_b_1` et al were meant as examples - as outlined before, those values have to be unique and generated using `StringUtility::getUniqueId('NEW')`. Anyway, I've removed underscores and added another notes section on identifiers...

Comment: What if I want to add a new IRRE record and add it to an existing parent wich already has IRRE records? Do I have to fetch the current values from the databse before and add the NEW uid to the current value?